# How to validate POCO object

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, validation, poco

I am working on a WPF EF application, i want to validate POCO objects, but i don't want a specific validation, i want more of a generic method to validate all my POCO entities, like if all the non nullable properties have values, all my data annotations are satisfied.

Kindly guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Code Generation via T4 Templates:

Resource:

http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/19/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4---templated-code-generation.aspx

Using this, you can generate validation code based on the properties your objects contain and more.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply validation attribute on your class, and when saving, to catch DbEntityValidationException and figure out the detailed validation error message.

Here is a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959) on this topic. The example is in asp.net mvc, but the validation piece should apply to WPF too.